# How do I print SQL syntaxed code as string in Python?

Tags: python, sql

So I need to print in console this:

`print(f"INSERT INTO TABLE{i+1} ({fin_prnt[i].keys()[1:-1]})")`

but PyCharm keeps highlighting `INSERT INTO` as SQL syntax and it produces an error when executing. Is there a way I could print that paragraph as string in console output?

Thanks

Comment: show more code - where `i` comes from? what is `fin_prnt` ?

Comment: try this: print('INSERT INTO TABLE{0}'.format(fin_prnt[i].keys()[1:-1] + 1))

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed any settings in PyCharm?

The print works for me fine (Version 2021.2).